# Android: device not supported

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-version

I have been facing problem of device not supported even though I don't find any such permission issue. So my concern is, are there any website or tools that could compare and tell why this application is not supported in some selected "abc" device. I found my application is not supported in samsung galaxy duos, but permission and version doesn't look like a problem as I see. How do other android developers check this?

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.beep11.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.beep11.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: post your manifest file

Comment: how u get it know that its not working in duos..?

Comment: @Manmohan when i tried to download from marketplace it says not supported..

Comment: @SpringBreaker i have added Manifest file

Comment: All permissions seems to be ok.Could you share you app link in the comment? You can later delete it.

Comment: @SpringBreaker https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.beep11